# when oauth2 authoration code grant flow, redirect_uri parameter is really optional?

Tags: oauth-2.0

In [RFC6749#setion-4.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1) introduces redirect_uri is optional.

But above **Authorization Code Flow** step (A), (C), (D) and also (E) describes what redirect_uri does.
And especially step (E) describes like following..

> and ensures that the redirection URI
> received matches the URI used to redirect the client in
> step (C).

So I confused when I saw section 4.1.1.
I think maybe this document not wrong, just stupid I did not understand.

Please tell me why `redirect_uri` parameter is optional.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will find some rules in the [RFC6749 section 3.1.2.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-3.1.2.3). From my POV it should always be set to avoid security issues (e.g. a malicious app changed the client configuration and setup its own redirect uri). By the way, this parameter is required when used for some authentication flows with OpenID Connect (see [OIDC Core specification section 3.2.2.1](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitAuthRequest))

Comment: Thank you @FlorentMorselli. I did not look the document carefully. And I forgot about the redirect_uri when registering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [rfc6749#section-2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2), describes:

> **When registering a client**, the client developer SHALL:
> o  **provide its client redirection URIs** as described in Section 3.1.2.

in rfc, `SHALL` means `MUST`, `REQUIRED`.
([Key words for use in RFCs to Indicate Requirement Levels](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119#section-1))

And let's see [rfc6749#section-3.1.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2.3) which mentioned by @Florent Morselli.

> **If multiple redirection URIs have been registered**,
> **if only part of the redirection URI has been registered**,
> or **if no redirection URI has been registered**,
> the client MUST include a redirection URI with the authorization request using the "redirect_uri" request parameter.

---

### Conclusion

If we provided **only one** complete redirection uri when registering client, redirect_uri is optional when authorization request.

#### warning

If the "redirect_uri" parameter was included in the **authorization request**, you MUST include it in **access token request**. details [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is in step (C) (of the same [RFC6749#section-4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1)):

> the authorization server redirects the user-agent back to the client
> using the redirection URI provided earlier (in the request **or during
> client registration**).

So if there is no `redirect_uri` in Authorization Request then authorization server use the default url which have been set during client registration (as described in [rfc6749#section-2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2) which @galcyurio mentioned in his answer).

Also in [#section-3.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2):

> 3.1.2.  Redirection Endpoint
>
> After completing its interaction with the resource owner, the
> authorization server directs the resource owner's user-agent back to
> the client. The authorization server redirects the user-agent **to the
> client's redirection endpoint previously established with the
> authorization server during the client registration process** or when
> making the authorization request.